# How to keep SVG typography for web consistent?

Tags: svg, responsive-design, cross-browser, typography

I have created an SVG logo for my online portfolio. However for some reason the typography within my logo is not consistent across the various Mobile devices. for example:

Displaying **correctly** on desktop with Chrome v46 and Safari 9.0.1:

[image: Desktop View]

Displaying **incorrectly** with iPhone and iPad using the Safari app:

[image: iphone View]
[image: iPad View]

How can I make this SVG typography consistent across various browsers and devices?

Comment: Create a custom font and ship it with your application.

Comment: Thanks for responding @RobertLongson, however could you please elaborate?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face

Comment: Although I didn't perform this method. I still learn't something new which is always a plus. In this scenario I simply edited the SVG text into an object in adobe illustrator. All works fine now. However I still thank you for you're response @RobertLongson. Cheers!

Comment: That makes the text non-accessible which means screen readers for blind people won't read it out and it can't be selected for copy/paste either.

Comment: Good point. Thanks I'll look into it more closely. Cheers